# Duck typing Vs class based Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, duck-typing

Using DuckTyping approach, below are two classes `Duck` & `Person`,

```
class Duck:
   def quack(self):
       print('Quack')

   def fly(self):
       print('Flap')

class Person:
   def quack(self):
       print('I\'m quacking like a duck')

   def walk(self):
       print('Walk')

def quackFlap(creature):
    try: 
       creature.quack()
    except: # EAFP
       print('Cannot quack')

    try:
       creature.flap() # Using hasattr() will violate EAFP
    except: # EAFP
       print('Cannot flap') 

donald = Duck()
quackFlap(donald)

p = Person()
quackFlap(p)  # Duck Typing approach says, Person is not Duck.
```

Using class based inheritance approach, below are two classes `Bird` & `Duck`,

```
class Bird(object):
   def quack(self):
       print('Quack')

   def fly(self):
       print('Fly')

class Duck(Bird):
   def quack(self):
       print('I\'m quacking like a duck')
   def fly(self):
       print('Flap')

def quackFlap(creature):
    if isinstance(creature, Bird):
       creature.quack()
       creature.flap()

b = Bird()
quackFlap(b)

d = Duck()
quackFlap(d) # Inheritance allowed isinstance() check - Error handling
```

**Question:**

1) Does DuckTyping avoid Subclassing? because on subclassing, we do not see the necessity of DuckTyping approach

2) When DuckTyping is better than class based inheritance?

Comment: That's a really bad use of try/catch.  A missing method is almost certainly going to raise AttributeError, but there are a lot of cases where  a method could raise AttributeError itself.  So I'd actually use hasattr rather than try/catch, and even if I were using try/except, I'd be careful to only handle AttributeError

Comment: I'm trying to articulate why I think this is a bad question.  Partially it's that it's opinion based; partially it is not clear to me you have a good enough starting place.  I think if you were to focus on something like what are the tradeoffs between duck typing and subclassing, it would be a more clear question.  I tried to answer that, but found it was too broad for me to come up with something useful.

Comment: @SamHartman If you use hasattr() then weren't you violating EAFP? using hasattr() will be like taking the permission before using it. sn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying that EAFP produces fragile code in this case, and it's a bad approach.  It's a tool, not a religion; sometimes it works well, sometimes it does not.

Comment: I didn't get the point of downvoting the OP. Even if the code has issues, the question is still valid. Which rule did he break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Does DuckTyping avoid Subclassing? because on subclassing, we do
>   not the necessity of DuckTyping approach

Not at all. Duck typing only turns unnecessary doing casts/checkings to the subclass type when you need to access something that is not defined on the superclass. But with a good design and a proper use of polymorphism you avoid doing this (using instanceof + cast to access the particularity of a subclass).

> 2) When DuckTyping is better than class based inheritance?

It really depends... Inheritance should be avoided when there is no "IS A" relationship between the classes, mainly when it's used just as a mean to re-utilize code. When there is an "IS A" relationship, and the code relies on the use of "instanceof", it's a sign of a bad design, i.e., that polymorphism isn't being properly used.

Duck typing is a handy way to have a polymorphic code without relying on abstract classes/interfaces like Java, for instance. But an abstract class/interface defines a contract. With duck typing you can introduce subtle bugs in your code due this lack of formal relationship. If your "quack" isn't a "quack" at all, you'll be in trouble. With inheritance, this is less likely to happen due the contractual nature of subclassing abstract classes.

Comment: Answer to first part was not clear. I did not get this *Duck typing only turns unnecessary doing casts/checkings to the subclass type when you need to access something that is not defined on the superclass*

Comment: In a static typed language, calling a method undefined on the base class will not compile. So, without ducktyping, if you need to call anything that is not defined in the base class, you need to make a cast to the subclass, and use the instanceof operator to avoid a invalid cast raising an error.

Comment: Duck typing is used extensively in Python sklearn.  This really helps extend its functionality.  Users can build their custom algorithms using sklearn API to interface with sklearn.

Comment: Duck typing can be used alongside with type checking system, such as _mypy_. Having that, there is no gonna be any trouble with saying a wrong "quack".

Comment: Not directly relevant to the python code in the original question. But FYI, duck typing in Go can check the issue "if your quack isn't a quack" at compile time.